# Get expanded attribute JQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes, sapui5

I got this code snippet:

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
    //#oTree-TreeCont: oTree -> ID des Tree, -TreeCont -> Konstante die den Content Bereich anspricht
    $('#oTree-TreeCont ul li').click(function(){
        var $aria = $(this).attr("aria-expanded");
        if($aria){ //Element wurde aufgeklappt
            alert($aria);
            var clickedNode = $(this).attr("id"); //Erfrage ID
            //Lade alle Childs der 'clickedNode'
            sap.ui.getCore().byId("idOrganisation_Home1").getController().loadChildNodes(clickedNode);
        }
    });

}
```

I want, that if the Tree (SAPUI5) is expanded a method should load the child elements of this node. The problem is, it alerts "*true*", but also "*false*".

Why could this happen? This part `if($aria){ }` should test if the value is true, but also when it is false, the body of the `if` statement is executed, why?

Thanks for every help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because currently the attribute value is treating as a string value, not the boolean value.
You need to check like this,

```
if($aria=="true")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm totally new to this whole topic, thanks a lot :)